# Tasks and WaitAll/WhenAll

Tags: c#, asynchronous, win-universal-app

Could you help me to speed up/optimize this code:

```
var keys = xRoot.Elements("key").Select(key => new { ID = int.Parse(key.Attribute("id").Value), VerificationCode = key.Attribute("verificationCode").Value });

var tasks = keys.Select(key => EveOnlineClient.GetAccountStatusAsync(key.ID, key.VerificationCode));

var tasks2 = keys.Select(key => EveOnlineClient.GetAPIKeyInfoAsync(key.ID, key.VerificationCode).ContinueWith(x =>
    {
        var characters = x.Result.Characters;

        var tasks3 = characters.Select(character => EveOnlineClient.GetCharacterSheetAsync(key.ID, key.VerificationCode, character.ID));
        var tasks4 = characters.Select(character => EveOnlineClient.GetSkillInTrainingAsync(key.ID, key.VerificationCode, character.ID));

        Task.WaitAll(tasks3.ToArray());
        Task.WaitAll(tasks4.ToArray());
    }));

await Task.WhenAll(tasks.Concat(tasks2));
```

Comment: What have you done to indicate you need to optimize this code? What is the bottleneck?

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow! It looks like you are asking for help in optimizing your code. You should post this question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for help on optimization.

Answer (score 0):

If I may offer one suggestion. I've found that **WHEN APPLICABLE**, using a list offers insignificantly, however more nevertheless processing speed and less allocated memory. .ToList(), while it does essentially boil down to the same format since it stores its information dynamically, tends to offer less allocated memory in the long run on the heap. When viewing other questions about Lists vs Arrays, I've learned that the goal and essentially the necessity for saving what could be insignificant time and memory[though possibly **Significant** time and memory, is to profile your code and see which would be more demonstrable in the long run.